# Sharing part of a git repo

Tags: git

I am a git newbie, so I may be missing something obvious.

I have a local git repo in this form

```
/.git
/Project-1/
/Project-2/
/Project-3/
/Project-4/
...
/Project-x/
...
/Project-y/
....
/Shared-Code/
```

Each project is a plugin for a host program. The developers of that program want to include 2 of my plugins in the release of their product. To that end they have provided a github repository in which to place my code. The issue is, I only want to upload /Project-x, /Project-y, and /Shared-Code.

I have looked here and elsewhere. The closest thing I could find suggested that I really should have 2 repos. I don't mind having 2 repos. I don't even care if they maintain the same change histories, although it would be nice if they did.

I could easily enough copy /Project-x, /Project-y, and /Shared-Code into a new place and create a new repo. My question is, would I be better off copying or using symlinks? Or is there a more "git" way of doing this?

Comment: The git way is to have multiple repos that each hold one project. you can have a super-repository containing the other repositories using git submodules for example.

Comment: Sounds interesting. So shared code would be a separate repo as well? Do you have a suggestion how I can preserve my change history if I move to separate repos?

Comment: I'd put shared code inside some form of library that I would version in a separate git repo. this git repo can then be included inside application repositories using git-submodule for example. If you want to split an existing repository based on directories, and keep history you need `git filter-branch`. I invite you to search stackoverflow, there are several very good answer on this.

Comment: Nota : the "optimal" solution depends on a lot of factors. this is a general approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [git submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to do that.

Of course, you could also create .gitignores that ignore the folders for the recipients (or you) by blocking the other folders as shown in the [gitignore docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in Git).

Comment: I did read the docs on git submodules, but I couldn't quite tell how I would get from my current format to using submodules. It seems like I want to go the opposite direction. Because I am a newbie I really need an ELI5.